# NullPointerException when running kaptDebugKotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, nullpointerexception, kapt

my gradle instance is not being able to compile a task on a determined Mac, this device is fresh so no old artefacts from Gradle or Kotlin are installed. The command to trigger it is `./gradlew app:kaptDebugKotlin` (it's also called by a Fastlane script but it's possible not related since the problem happens independently).

Stacktrace:

https://gist.github.com/ppamorim/1965936e3f1dea17c5448b54d8b287cb

On my old Mac this script runs fine. I have no idea what's happening. The project on the new Mac compiles fine.

The machine that is not compiling runs macOS Mojave and the one which compiles run macOS High Sierra.
Both machines run the same Kotlin(1.3.31), Java(openJDK 12.0.1), Gradle (5.4.1), Android Studio(3.4.1) versions.

Comment: Solved, already solved in another post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53486842/2430555